# Regex for capture fields from multiple format data logs

Tags: regex

I have a Regex for capturing certain fields from logs. It working fine for one type of log entry. but sometimes, I get little different format and it capture different field.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AYjX7j/4)

In the given example, there are 2 different log entry. Regex working fine for first entry.

In second entry, there are 3 different sets

```
  1.  314624K->314624K(419456K)
  2.  9862316K->9542223K(12478080K)
  3.  12261641K->11966292K(12478080K)
```

my regex is skipping the 1st one and capturing the next two. I want to capture first two occurrence.

My regex:

```
(?=[^P]*(?:ParNew|P.*ParNew|PSYoungGen|DefNew)).*?(?P<ParNew_before_1>\d+)K->(?P<ParNew_after_1>\d+)K\((?P<young_heap_size>\d+)K\), (?P<par_new_duration>\d+\.\d+) secs\] (?P<ParNew_before_2>\d+)K\->(?P<ParNew_after_2>\d+)K\((?P<total_heap_size>\d+)
```

I think problem is that i am using ".*?". I have tried to change it with \s+ but its not working as well.

Comment: Give a look into using a negative character class like [^(]+   instead of .*?

Comment: @sniperd : thanks but its not working 

https://regex101.com/r/lP7zJ6/1

Comment: Your current question is not clear. What are the rules? Try https://regex101.com/r/vwjY3l/1

Comment: In the second entry, after the first `secs]` the regex is searching something like `\d+K->\d+K\(\d+` that is missing, so it skips the first part and goes to the second `secs]`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew. in this case its extracting all 3 sets . I want only these data:   [ParNew: 314624K->314624K(419456K), 0.0000314 secs]128098.792: [CMS: 11947017K->11966292K(12058624K)

Comment: @AnkitGoyal: what you have to do will be more clear if you read that: https://regex101.com/r/tjbGUn/1

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte:  I have made some small changes in ur regex and now its working fine. https://regex101.com/r/tjbGUn/2

Comment: @AnkitGoyal: Why not, but it's a bad idea to remove the beginning of the pattern, see the improvement with it (the number of steps is divided by ~7): https://regex101.com/r/tjbGUn/5

Comment: I suggest that one of you should post the pattern as an answer.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte: I agree !! it looks better now :)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: It's already there. click on the regex101 link.